SVG Pattern Fill Works on <rect> but Scales Incorrectly on <polygon>
I am working with an SVG that includes a  fill, which displays correctly when applied to a <rect>, but when I apply the same pattern to a <polygon>, it scales down to an extremely small size. If I use a solid color, like fill="yellow", the polygon appears at the correct size and shape, so I believe the issue is specific to how the pattern is being applied to the .
<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
pointer-events="none">
<!-- Rectangle filled correctly with the pattern -->
<rect width="512" height="512" fill="url(#pattern0_1011_2713)" />

<!-- Polygon with scaling issue when using the pattern -->
<polygon points="256,0 512,128 256,256 0,128"
       fill="url(#pattern0_1011_2713)"
       style="pointer-events: auto;" />

<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern0_1011_2713" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="512" 
    height="512">
    <use xlink:href="#image0_1011_2713" transform="scale(0.00195512)" width="512" 
    height="512" />
  </pattern>
<image id="image0_1011_2713" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..." width="512" 
height="512" />
</defs>
</svg>

What I've Tried:
Using Solid Colors: When I set fill="yellow" on the polygon, it displays at the correct shape and size, so the issue seems specific to the pattern application.
Pattern Scaling: I experimented with patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" and transform="scale(...)" values on the  element, but these changes haven’t resolved the scaling issue.
Goal:
I want the pattern to fill the polygon in the same way it fills the rectangle—without scaling down or shifting. I am trying to build a Settlers of Catan type game using React and this SVG is for the land but as you can see below, the SVG itself is 512 x 512 but the visible area of it is the polygon which I've mapped out ie (0, 128)(128, 128)(512, 128)(128, 0). The reason for this is that I only want the visible part to enable pointer-events 
Question:
How can I adjust the  or  settings to ensure the pattern fills the polygon correctly without scaling issues? Is there a specific approach for using patterns with polygons that I might be overlooking?
Thanks for any insights or solutions!

You're tripping yourself up with unit definitions. I think this version gets you what you want.


<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
pointer-events="none">
<!-- Rectangle filled correctly with the pattern -->
<rect width="512" height="512" fill="url(#pattern0_1011_2713)" />

<!-- Polygon with scaling issue when using the pattern -->
<polygon transform="translate(0 -50)" points="256,0 512,128 256,256 0,128"
       fill="url(#pattern0_1011_2713)"
       style="pointer-events: auto;" />

<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern0_1011_2713" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
    <use xlink:href="#image0_1011_2713" x="0" y="0"/>
  </pattern>
  
<image id="image0_1011_2713" xlink:href="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/17/25/45/240_F_317254576_lKDALRrvGoBr7gQSa1k4kJBx7O2D15dc.jpg" width="512" height="512" x="0" y="0" />
</defs>
</svg>



